# How to implement query schema on mongodb for ecommerce in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to make a product catalog service for an ecommerce system.
I have "Clothes" products, that have variations on "Size" and "Color" e.g.:

```
    "Title": "Nike Hoodie Tiger",
    "Price": 69.9,
    "Vars": [
        {
            "Sku": "NH01",
            "Attrs": [{"Size": "XL"}, {"Color": "white"}],
            "Quantity" : 3
        },
                {
            "Sku": "NH02",
            "Attrs": [{"Size": "L"}, {"Color": "white"}],
            "Quantity" : 0
        },
        {
            "Sku": "NH03",
            "Attrs": [{"Size": "M"}, {"Color": "white"}],
            "Quantity" : 1
        }
    ]
```

Then I have "Television" products that have variations on Resolutions:

```
    "Title": "Sony Bravia 40",
    "Price": 339.9,
    "Vars": [
        {
            "Sku": "TV01",
            "Attrs": [{"Resolution": "FullHD"}],
            "Quantity" : 3
        },
                {
            "Sku": "TV01",
            "Attrs": [{"Resolution": "4K"}],
            "Quantity" : 0
        }
    ]
```

The Models for the Clothes products look like this in C#:

```
    public class Product
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public List<ProductVariations> Vars { get; set; }
    }

    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class ProductVariations
    {
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public List<ProductAttributes> Attrs { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductAttributes
    {
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

So what strategy should I use to support other product attributes, like the ones on Television?
What if in the future I want to add other products with totally different attributes? Do I have to rewrite my code to support these attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very nice question. Since you can't know the type being a future implementation and such, then you can only go with detail/value implementation.

Instead of attributes, your list could contain a data structure like this:

```
public class ProductDetail {
    public DetailType Type;
    public string Value;
}
```

Now your `attrs` can change to something like this

```
`[{ Type: 1, Value: "4k"}]`
```

And `DetailType` can be enum to save storage space.

If the detailType enum is a problem, you can do the following:

```
public class ProductDetail {
    public string Type;
    public string Value;
}

`[{ Type: "Resolution", Value: "4k"}]`
```

Comment: thats a nice approach, but it sitll needs to update the Enum every time a new attribute is added. Can I load the Vars as any kind of object and manipulate it, without using a Model class?